# how can i change the colour of mutiple optionbuttons with as little code as possible

Tags: vba

I have a spreadsheet with 70 rows x 6 columns containing 420 option buttons in groups of 6 ie group1 = optionbutton1, 71.141,211,281 and 351. Group2 = Optionbutton2,72,142,282 and 352.

This is the code I have for changing the background colour based on the value of the button:

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Change()

With OptionButton1

    If .Value Then
        .BackColor = vbRed ' or RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Else
        .BackColor = vbGreen ' or RGB(0,0,0)
    End If

End With

End Sub
```

I need to do this for all 420 option buttons, but this could take a while to replicate and stands more chance of missing entries.
Is there a way of shortening this code or changing the code to apply to any option button on the worksheet to change to red on true or green when false?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using an ActiveX Option Button and, unfortunately, I don't believe there is a way to get around having to have code associated with the Change or Click Events of each Option Button if you want it to automatically change the Controls BackColor when the user changes an option.

An alternative would be to use the Form Controls Option Button as with these you can set them all to run the same code whenever their selection is changed. Taking this approach you could have a single Method which will loop through every Option Button on the Sheet and change it's background colour dependent on its value.

The following is an example of how you could do this. In the Visual Basic editor add a new Module to your project. This function would be called whenever your Option Button is changed, and it will work through every Option Button on the Sheet and change its colour.

```
Sub optionButtonChange()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim formShape As shape

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

    For Each formShape In ws.Shapes
        If formShape.Type = MsoShapeType.msoFormControl Then
            If TypeName(formShape.OLEFormat.Object) = "OptionButton" Then
                If formShape.OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
                    formShape.OLEFormat.Object.Interior.Color = vbRed
                Else
                formShape.OLEFormat.Object.Interior.Color = vbGreen
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Set ws = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing


End Sub
```

Now for this to work you need to assign this to the Option Buttons 'macro' - you can do this manually by right clicking the Option Button and selecting it, or you can do it programmatically by applying it to every Option Button on the Sheet, as in the following example:

```
Sub changeOnAction()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim formShape As shape

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet

    For Each formShape In ws.Shapes
        If formShape.Type = MsoShapeType.msoFormControl Then
            If TypeName(formShape.OLEFormat.Object) = "OptionButton" Then
                ' Macro name format is "'<workbooks filename>'!functionToCall"
                formShape.OnAction = "'" & wb.Name & "'!optionButtonChange"
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Set formShape = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing

End Sub
```

To use this, make sure the Sheet with your Option Buttons on is open and from the Visual Basic editor simply run the code. Once that is done clicking any Option Button on your Sheet will trigger the initial code example and they should all re-colour automatically.